# Issues with sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am migrating an old code igniter application to WordPress. I have imported all of the data as custom posts (`product`), but the problem is on the old site, they reuse page slugs, causing some weird issues when WP pulls the post (as WordPress requires it to be unique by default). So, What I'm trying to figure out is how I can write a query or script that will go through and find all duplicate post-name's (from wp_posts) and add '-2', '-3', '-4' etc for all the duplicates. My other option would be to try and fix WordPress so I didn't need unique page slugs, but I don't even know where I would turn for that (although, if possible, this would be the best possible outcome!!).

If I run

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product'`

It returns 5973 results. Running

`SELECT DISTINCT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product'`

It returns 1800 rows, so doing this manually would be a huge amount of time.

I tried to write a script in php to output each individual query, but there is an error in my sql syntax that ultimately causes the first in each group of commands to apply to every matching result instead of the first result. Any ideas?

```
global $wpdb;

$distinct_post_names = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT DISTINCT post_name FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts WHERE post_type = "product" AND post_name != ""');

foreach( $distinct_post_names as $distinct_post ) {

    $these_posts = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts WHERE post_name = "' . $distinct_post->post_name .'" AND post_type="product"');

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($these_posts); $i++ ) {
        if ( $i != 0) {
            echo 'UPDATE ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts SET post_name = "' . $distinct_post->post_name . '-' . $i . '" WHERE post_name = "' . $distinct_post->post_name . '";<br>';
        }
    }

    echo '<br>';
}
```

Below is a sample of this output:

```
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-left-1" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-left-2" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-left-3" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-left-4" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-left-5" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-left-6" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-left-7" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-left";

UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-right-1" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-right";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-right-2" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-right";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-right-3" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-right";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-right-4" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-right";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-right-5" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-right";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-assembly-right-6" WHERE post_name = "headlight-assembly-right";

UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-1" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-2" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-3" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-4" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-5" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-6" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-7" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-8" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-9" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
UPDATE wp_o1y4a6ifud_posts SET post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left-10" WHERE post_name = "headlight-door-surround-left";
```

Any ideas whats wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the posts have duplicate names, and the logic you're using produces a query that updates all posts of title 'A' with 'A-1'.

You need to target the posts with a field other than the title. Try grabbing post IDs instead. So it would be:

```
global $wpdb;

$distinct_post_names = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT DISTINCT post_name FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts WHERE post_type = "product" AND post_name != ""');

foreach( $distinct_post_names as $distinct_post ) {

    $these_posts = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts WHERE post_name = "' . $distinct_post->post_name .'" AND post_type="product"');

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($these_posts); $i++ ) {
        if ( $i != 0) {
            echo 'UPDATE ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts SET post_name = "' . $distinct_post->post_name . '-' . $i . '" WHERE ID = "' . $these_posts[$i]->ID . '";<br>';
        }
    }

    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had done that with Excel a lot back in the day. But what if there are 1M rows or even just 10K.

**Do this in a test environment.** It's on you no matter what. But here is what I would do.

I know nothing about WordPress other than [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-primary-key-of-last-inserted-row-into-database) that I just looked up.

So I assume it has an id that is an int auto_increment and therefore it has to be the Primary Key.

### Schema

```
create table wp_posts
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    post_title varchar(1000) not null,
    post_type varchar(50) not null
);
insert wp_posts (post_title,post_type) values 
('a','product'),('a','service'),('d','product'),
('b','product'),('c','product'),('b','product'),('b','product'),('d','product'),('z','fancy');
```

### Peek at the data

```
SELECT id, post_title 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'product' 
order by post_title,id; -- give some weight to id, what the heck
+----+------------+
| id | post_title |
+----+------------+
|  1 | a          |
|  4 | b          |
|  6 | b          |
|  7 | b          |
|  5 | c          |
|  3 | d          |
|  8 | d          |
+----+------------+
```

### Show titles that represent duplicate titles (for products)

```
SELECT post_title,count(*) as theCount 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'product' 
group by post_title 
having theCount>1;
+------------+----------+
| post_title | theCount |
+------------+----------+
| b          |        3 |
| d          |        2 |
+------------+----------+
```

### Make a derived table out of above in a join, to limit output to just the duplicate titles.

```
select * 
from wp_posts w 
join 
(   SELECT post_title,count(*) as theCount 
    FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    group by post_title 
    having theCount>1 
) xxx -- this is the alias, every derived table needs an alias 
on w.post_title=xxx.post_title;


+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id | post_title | post_type | post_title | theCount |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|  4 | b          | product   | b          |        3 |
|  6 | b          | product   | b          |        3 |
|  7 | b          | product   | b          |        3 |
|  3 | d          | product   | d          |        2 |
|  8 | d          | product   | d          |        2 |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

-- add a row number column to the above, incrementing from 1 and up for each grouping of title

```
select w.*,
@rn:=if(w.post_title=@grp,@rn+1,1) as rownum,
@grp:=coalesce(null,w.post_title) as theGrp
from wp_posts w 
join 
(   SELECT post_title,count(*) as theCount 
    FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    group by post_title 
    having theCount>1 
) xxx -- this is the alias, every derived table needs an alias 
on w.post_title=xxx.post_title
cross join (select @rn:=0,@grp='') params;


+----+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
| id | post_title | post_type | rownum | theGrp |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
|  4 | b          | product   |      1 | b      |
|  6 | b          | product   |      2 | b      |
|  7 | b          | product   |      3 | b      |
|  3 | d          | product   |      1 | d      |
|  8 | d          | product   |      2 | d      |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

That *could* be enough for you to do what you want with that output eyeballed, and the routine above utilized in your other sql generator (tweaked, and using PK `id`).

But let's just do it all in one update statement and get it over with fast.

That requires grabbing the last chunk of code and making yet another derived table out of it.

And an "update with join" pattern

```
update wp_posts
join
(   select w.*,
    @rn:=if(w.post_title=@grp,@rn+1,1) as rownum,
    @grp:=coalesce(null,w.post_title) as theGrp
    from wp_posts w 
    join 
    (   SELECT post_title,count(*) as theCount 
        FROM wp_posts 
        WHERE post_type = 'product' 
        group by post_title 
        having theCount>1 
    ) xxx -- this is the alias, every derived table needs an alias 
    on w.post_title=xxx.post_title
    cross join (select @rn:=0,@grp='') params
) xyz -- every derived table needs an alias 
on xyz.id=wp_posts.id
set wp_posts.post_title=concat(xyz.post_title,'-',cast(xyz.rownum as char(5)));
-- 5 rows(s) affected
```

### Results

```
select * from wp_posts;
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | post_title | post_type |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | a          | product   |
|  2 | a          | service   |
|  3 | d-1        | product   |
|  4 | b-1        | product   |
|  5 | c          | product   |
|  6 | b-2        | product   |
|  7 | b-3        | product   |
|  8 | d-2        | product   |
|  9 | z          | fancy     |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

post_title of "a" was left in as an edge-condition for you to ponder, as it was a service for the 2nd one.

Here is a references on [Advanced MySQL user variable techniques](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/). The cross join seen simply initializes those variables at the beginning. Nothing more, nothing less. As the output experiences a new grouping of titles, it merely sets the rownumber back to 1. It might look cryptic. Ok it does look cryptic.

Good luck. Oh, and **Do this in a test environment.**

Comment: Wow what an incredibly thorough post! I'm gonna read through this and I'll comment if I have any questions, but thanks!